# How to Display top search terms from a MySQL database and grouped by date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database that looks a lot like this:

```
Term-----------LOB---------Date------
dde            JM Part A   2016-07-01
drug waste     JM Part A   2016-07-01
drug waste     JM Part A   2016-07-01
Duplicates     JM Part A   2016-07-01
credit balance JM Part B   2016-07-01
drug waste     JM Part B   2016-07-01
```

So, I want the TOP 4 (or n) 'terms' per LOB (lob is a category) - per Month

So in this example it could be

```
JM Part A July 2016
--dde            - 7
--drug waste     - 5
--credit balance - 3
--duplicates     - 1
```

```
JM Part B - July 2016
--dde            - 7
--discharge stats- 5
--credit balances- 3
--overpayment    - 1
```

Alas, I am a little lost. The best I am able to do so far is

```
SELECT term, lob, COUNT(term) uid_count
FROM qs
GROUP BY lob
ORDER BY uid_count DESC
LIMIT 5
```

This seems to display the top 5 search terms for all lobs and all date ranges.

So any help would be greatly appreciated. I am looking at displaying the reports on a PHP page.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: how many  distinct Lob you have ?

Comment: could you show us the result of your query

Comment: did you try splitting the problem in a number of queries?

Comment: show us your php program

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ go where and build a fiddle, it will be easy to help afterwards

Comment: You may want a [crosstab query](http://evolt.org/node/26896/).

Comment: Ty all - had no idea bout 'sqlfiddle' - scaisEdge answer works GREAT. I just have 5 distinct LOB so this works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of distinct Lob is low .. you can use union

```
 (select Term, count(*) 
 from my_tbale 
 where Lob = 'JM Part A'
 group by Term, `Date`
 order by count(*) desc limit 5)
 union  
 (select Term, count(*) 
 from my_tbale 
 where Lob = 'JM Part B'
 group by Term, `Date`
 order by count(*) desc limit 5)
```